# Discord.py bot to display random subreddit post

Tags: python, discord.py, reddit

I'm trying to get this bot to post images from subreddits, I get no errors, the bot loads properly, but when I run the command to try and call the command to display an image from the subreddit r/memes it doesn't respond, I've tried to put in small signals to see if it reads it and it doesn't.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, subred = "memes"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(limit = 5)

    for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)
    
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    em = discord.Embed(title = name)
    
    em.set_image(url = url)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

sorry if this seems obvious, this is very much out of my comfort zone, but I want to try and improve. Any help will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There’s a few things that could be happening here that we need to break down. Once we do that, you can ask a better question to fix your issue.

1. Is your bot getting called? A simple way to test this is to throw a massive error to stop your program
2. Can it respond? If your bot is being called, make sure it can actually respond to the message your sending.
3. Are you getting data from Reddit correctly? Test this outside of your bot just in the python repl and see if data comes back.
4. If you get data back, are there any errors thrown?

If you can do/answer these, I think it will help you debug your issue. If you run into problems doing these, ask away.

In the future, please try to include steps you’ve tried, things that have failed, and any errors you have so we can help you.